# Difference between elements of subsequent pairs in numpy arrays (not numpy.diff)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Is there quick way to calculate the difference between two elements in subsequent pairs in python arrays? For example, consider `x`:

```
x = np.array([1,5,3,8])
```

How can I calculate from x the differences between subsequent pairs? My desired output is:

```
np.array([4,5])
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can slice in strides of 2 and subtract:

```
>>> x[1::2] - x[::2]
array([4, 5])
```

Another solution is to reshape and call `np.diff`:

```
>>> np.diff(x.reshape(-1, 2), axis=1).ravel()     
array([4, 5])
```

---

A generalised version of this that works for any `N * M` array would look something like this -

```
r = np.diff(x.reshape(-1, 2), axis=1).reshape(-1, x.shape[1] // 2)
```

Comment: Hey thanks for editing my comment to make it more legible. Your answer does provide the solution so thanks! However it does work if you scale it to any arbitrary 2 dimensional array with an even number of rows. For example if I want to to this for a N by M array where M is even. For example: x = np.array([[1,5,3,8],[1,2,3,4]]) with desired output: array([[4,5],[1,1]])

Comment: @user7740248 Are you asking or are you telling?

Comment: Sorry I posted my response on accident I just edited for a follow up question

Comment: @user7740248 Okay. For any N * M array where M is even, this will work: `np.diff(x.reshape(-1, 2), axis=1).reshape(-1, x.shape[1] // 2)`.